# Acessar e listar arquivos em um servidor FTP

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, Gostaria de acessar e listar arquivos pasta/PDF's em um servidor FTP usando um App, utilizo `fragment` e a versão do Android e da 4 até a atual 9.
O que pesquisei até o momento não consegui resolver esse problema, não achei nada de concreto.

Alguém poderia me dar o caminho?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isto se não funcionar eu mando outra (String Caminho,String user,String pass):

```
static List<DirectoryItem> GetDirectoryInformation(string address, string username, string password) {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(address);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            List<DirectoryItem> returnValue = new List<DirectoryItem>();
            string[] list = null;

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                list = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }

            foreach (string line in list) {

                string data = line;
                string date = data.Substring(0, 17);
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
                data = data.Remove(0, 24);
                string dir = data.Substring(0, 5);
                bool isDirectory = dir.Equals("<dir>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                data = data.Remove(0, 5);
                data = data.Remove(0, 10);

                string name = data;

                DirectoryItem item = new DirectoryItem();
                item.BaseUri = new Uri(address);
                item.DateCreated = dateTime;
                item.IsDirectory = isDirectory;
                item.Name = name;

                Debug.WriteLine(item.AbsolutePath);
                item.Items = item.IsDirectory ? GetDirectoryInformation(item.AbsolutePath, username, password) : null;

                returnValue.Add(item);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: Onde está esse `List<DirectoryItem>` ?

Comment: Não consegui @Gonçalo Garrido, não sei se é pq estou usando fragmento, não estou conseguindo importar as classes.